# Error del servidor usando la librería de fullcalendar

Tags: laravel, angular, fullcalendar

Tengo un error al subir mi aplicación con Angular versión 9.1.15.
De manera local funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de alojar la aplicación en el servidor arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión de fullcalendar es la 5.5.0 y fue instalada usando esta guía:

```
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular
```

El servidor es Apache 2.4.29
Se utiliza Laravel 7.30.4
PHP 7.3.20-1

Comment: Parece similar este error:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/340 Espero alguien responda si se deba a un problema de importaciones o a un problema con la configuración del servidor..